# MVC3 Partial model validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm in trouble and ask for your help.

I have a simple class

```
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public string a { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string c { get;set; }

    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

I created a simple form to submit new entity instance and it works.
I'm in trouble for edit:
Edit form displays 'a' and 'b' properties. Since 'c' can be submitted only in new Entities and must not be displayed ( do not ask why ), on my update method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Test t)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     //get the m instance
      UpdateModel(m,//other params);
      ValidateModel(m);
    }
    //saving code
}
```

Obiously `ModelState.IsValid` is always false (because 'c' is required', but it's null) and `UpdateModel` throws an Exception (for same reason).
How can i say to MVC3 "Do not validate this field, only in this controller method?"
Obiously i won't write unvalidated fields in model class! I have to update only 'b' property.
Thank you.

Comment: have you thought about using FluentValidation, that way you can use RuleSets and within the controller set which RuleSet is validated against.

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way is to create an other view model for this partial view.

Answer (score 1):

Create another viewmodel for this view and validate against that viewmodel instead of the entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @{
   object htmlAttribute = null;
   if(Model.Id > 0)
   {
       htmlAttribute = new { disabled = "disabled" };
   }
 }

 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.C, htmlAttributes)
```

when disabled, C will not be validated

Comment: I simply decomposed Model and get needed property as single values in parameters of method. It worked but i do not like it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is in Edit mode, make the field a hidden property with a "default" value that you evaluate in the controller. If you want to not display the property on the form at all and still have it required, then you shouldn't use the "ModeState.IsValid" and do your own validation.

Example of the property being hidden:

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string id) {
        return View((string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) ? new Test { a = "new" } : FakeRepository.Data(id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Test model) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            if (model.a == "new") {
                //Create a new record
            } else {
                //Update Record
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public static class FakeRepository {
        public static Test Data(string a) {
            return new Test {
                a = a,
                b = "B",
                c = "C"
            };
        }
    }
```

**Entity**

```
public class Test {
    [Key]
    [Display(Name="A Property")]
    public string a { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "C Property")]
    public string c { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "B Property")]
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.a)       


        @if (Model.a != "new") { 
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.c)
        } else { 
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.c)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.c)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.c)
            </div>
        }    

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.b)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.b)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.b)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Now**:

*.../Edit/Something* will hide "C"

*.../Edit/* will display "C"